# Java representing time class

Tags: java

I want to represent time with my time class. I can't use get and set methods.Only I can use listed methods on the code.But it doesn't work.
It returns 0:0:0.

```
 public int addHours(int hours)
      {
          if(hours>=0&&hours<=23)
          {      
          return hours;
          }
          return 0;
      }
      public int addMinutes(int minutes)
      {
          if(minutes>=0&&minutes<=59)
          {
              return minutes;
          }
        return 0;  
      }
      public int addSeconds(int seconds)
      {
          if(seconds>=0&&seconds<=59)
          {
              return seconds;
          }
      return 0;
      }
      public String showTime()
      {
        return hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
      }
}
```

Comment: your `add...`-methods don't add anything. Why are they called "addSeconds" and "addMinutes"? You should either refactor the code to actually add the value or rename the methods.

Comment: You should save them in your global variables like `this.hours=hours` otherwise their values will not be saved

Comment: use the java 8 time api, seriously! (LocalTime is what you're looking for). if you depend on java 7 or newer, then use JodaTime

Comment: int hours;
      int minutes;
      int seconds;
      public Time()
      {
       
      }
      public Time(int hours)
      {
       this.hours=hours;
      }
      public Time(int hours,int minutes)
      { 
       this.hours=hours;
       this.minutes=minutes;
      }
      public Time(int hours,int minutes,int seconds)
      {
       this.hours=hours;
       this.minutes=minutes;
       this.seconds=seconds;
      }  //where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

your code does nothing.

you need to do something like this:

```
public void addHours( int hours ){
   this.hours += hours; // add hours
   this.hours %= 24; // roll over at 24 hours
}

public void addMinutes( int minutes ){
    this.minutes += minutes; // add minutes
    addHours(this.minutes/60); // carry over to hours
    this.minutes %= 60; // roll over at 60 minutes
}

public void addSeconds( int seconds ){
    this.seconds += seconds; // add seconds
    addMinutes(seconds/60); // carry over to minutes
    this.seconds %= 60; // roll over at 60 seconds
}
```

(it probably won't matter, but this is not thread safe at all)

but this is generally a bad idea. Java 8 has a beautiful time api, pre Java-8 there is the JodaTime library (which is actually the basis of the Java 8 time api). It seems what you want to do could benefit from LocalTime:

```
LocalTime t = LocalTime.of(13,50,27).addHours(1).addMinutes(1).addSeconds(1); 
System.out.println(t.toString()); 

// prints 14:51:28
```

Comment: thanks your solution but i found solution myself,thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.Calendar and java.text.SimpleDateFormat:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 5);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: I Can't use any other methods or packages.Only listed methods

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek you should specify in your question that it is a homework and that you're forced to respect constraints.